# Android studio getting skipping frames error and application not responding dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-studio-3.0

I am a newbie to android studio(Android App Development).

Facing issues while developing Android application. Getting following error

`"Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."`

and showing dialog `"application not responding"`.

Iam creating/writing xml file to external storage using sqlite database.

Kindly help me How to fix this?

**DbHelper.java**

```
package com.techyour.bank;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static final String DB_NAME = "my_bank_data.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_banks";

    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String AGE = "age";
    public static final String GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String DOB = "dob";
    public static final String COUNTRY = "country";
    public static final String PH_NO = "ph_no";


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " ( " +
                _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                NAME + " TEXT, " +
                AGE + " TEXT, " +
                GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                DOB + " TEXT, " +
                COUNTRY + " TEXT, " +
                PH_NO + " TEXT " +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        defaultData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void defaultData() {
        GetSet a1 = new GetSet("Alice", "20", "Male", "1994", "USA", "9876543210");
        defaultData2(a1);
        GetSet a2 = new GetSet("Bob", "21", "Male", "1997", "UK", "4002639610");
        defaultData2(a2);
        GetSet a3 = new GetSet("Eve", "22", "Male", "1964", "INDIA", "7040576498");
        defaultData2(a3);
        GetSet a4 = new GetSet("Mildred Martin", "23", "Male", "1959", "USA", "2113309849");
        defaultData2(a4);
        GetSet a5 = new GetSet("Ruth    Hill", "24", "Male", "1918", "USA", "6296713680");
        defaultData2(a5);
        GetSet a6 = new GetSet("Justin  Baker", "25", "Male", "1976", "USA", "5113788645");
        defaultData2(a6);
        GetSet a7 = new GetSet("Carl    Coleman", "26", "Male", "1945", "USA", "9346135599");
        defaultData2(a7);
        GetSet a8 = new GetSet("Wanda   Mitchell", "27", "Male", "1909", "USA", "9134105633");
        defaultData2(a8);
        GetSet a9 = new GetSet("Joe Bennett", "28", "Male", "1915", "UK", "6383446319");
        defaultData2(a9);
        GetSet a10 = new GetSet("Willie Carter", "29", "Male", "1958", "USA", "5578230822");
        defaultData2(a10);
        GetSet a11 = new GetSet("Debra  Bryant", "21", "Male", "1980", "USA", "4818754159");
        defaultData2(a11);
        GetSet a12 = new GetSet("Christopher    Powell", "20", "Male", "1913", "USA", "0403170292");
        defaultData2(a12);
        GetSet a13 = new GetSet("Gloria Moore", "30", "Male", "1947", "USA", "5206569101");
        defaultData2(a13);
        GetSet a14 = new GetSet("Beverly    Nelson", "20", "Male", "1905", "UK", "9449903813");
        defaultData2(a14);
        GetSet a15 = new GetSet("Melissa    Davis", "22", "Female", "1955", "USA", "5961002003");
        defaultData2(a15);
        GetSet a16 = new GetSet("Janet  Price", "17", "Male", "1935", "USA", "1977492463");
        defaultData2(a16);
        GetSet a17 = new GetSet("Helen  Edwards", "20", "Male", "1910", "USA", "6834805918");
        defaultData2(a17);
        GetSet a18 = new GetSet("Craig  Garcia", "23", "Male", "1911", "INDIA", "0807332318");
        defaultData2(a18);
        GetSet a19 = new GetSet("Deborah    Jenkins", "20", "Male", "1935", "USA", "0068416390");
        defaultData2(a19);
        GetSet a20 = new GetSet("Tina   Stewart", "20", "Female", "1963", "USA", "1054983413");
        defaultData2(a20);
        GetSet a21 = new GetSet("Kimberly   Howard", "31", "Male", "1911", "USA", "9852591520");
        defaultData2(a21);
        GetSet a22 = new GetSet("Earl   Bailey", "20", "Male", "1948", "USA", "9546632144");
        defaultData2(a22);
        GetSet a23 = new GetSet("Wayne  Hernandez", "28", "Female", "1900", "INDIA", "9837178563");
        defaultData2(a23);
        GetSet a24 = new GetSet("Terry  Cook", "18", "Male", "1910", "USA", "8298923456");
        defaultData2(a24);
        GetSet a25 = new GetSet("Ronald Evans", "20", "Male", "1994", "USA", "4541427090");
        defaultData2(a25);
        GetSet a26 = new GetSet("Doris  Brooks", "20", "Male", "1958", "INDIA", "0960421257");
        defaultData2(a26);
        GetSet a27 = new GetSet("Sarah  Simmons", "19", "Female", "1982", "USA", "5305824976");
        defaultData2(a27);
        GetSet a28 = new GetSet("Frank  Thompson", "26", "Male", "1973", "USA", "9079724716");
        defaultData2(a28);
        GetSet a29 = new GetSet("Smith", "20", "Male", "1954", "USA", "6300051365");
        defaultData2(a29);
        GetSet a30 = new GetSet("Jhon", "27", "Male", "1989", "UK", "4545983296");
        defaultData2(a30);
    }

    private void defaultData2(GetSet getSet) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, getSet.getNAME());
        cv.put(AGE, getSet.getAGE());
        cv.put(GENDER, getSet.getGENDER());
        cv.put(DOB, getSet.getDOB());
        cv.put(COUNTRY, getSet.getCOUNTRY());
        cv.put(PH_NO, getSet.getPH_NO());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    public List<GetSet> getAllData(String where) {
        List<GetSet> list = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{where};
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + _ID + " = ?", selectionArgs);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                GetSet getSet = new GetSet();
                getSet.setNAME(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
                getSet.setAGE(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AGE)));
                getSet.setGENDER(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(GENDER)));
                getSet.setDOB(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DOB)));
                getSet.setCOUNTRY(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY)));
                getSet.setPH_NO(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PH_NO)));
                list.add(getSet);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return list;
    }

    public List<GetSet> getDataCount() {
        List<GetSet> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + NAME + " IS NOT NULL ", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                GetSet getSet = new GetSet();
                getSet.setNAME(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
                list2.add(getSet);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return list2;
    }

    public Cursor getDataById(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + _ID + " = ?", new String[]{id});
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.techyour.bank;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvData;

    DbHelper dbHelper;
    GetSet getSet;
    List<GetSet> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        tvData = findViewById(R.id.tvData);

        checkPermission();
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    public void ocBtnGetSet(View view) throws IOException {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        try {
            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "persons");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= dbHelper.getDataCount().size(); i++) {
            dataList = dbHelper.getAllData(String.valueOf(i));
            getSet = dataList.get(0);

            try {
                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "person");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "name");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getNAME());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "name");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "age");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getAGE());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "age");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "gender");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getGENDER());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "gender");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "dob");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getDOB());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "dob");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "country");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getCOUNTRY());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "country");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "ph_no");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getPH_NO());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "ph_no");

                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "person");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "persons");
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();

        tvData.append(writer.toString());

        writeXmlToSd(writer.toString());
    }

    private void writeXmlToSd(String data) {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AABBCC");

            if (!Dir.exists()) {
                Dir.mkdir();
            }

            File file = new File(Dir, "backup.xml");

            String text = data;

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SD Card Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**GetSet.java**

```
package com.techyour.bank;

/**
 * Created by Vamshi Krishna on 01-10-2018 001.
 */

class GetSet {
    private String NAME;
    private String AGE;
    private String GENDER;
    private String DOB;
    private String COUNTRY;
    private String PH_NO;

    GetSet() {
    }

    public GetSet(String NAME, String AGE, String GENDER, String DOB, String COUNTRY, String PH_NO) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.AGE = AGE;
        this.GENDER = GENDER;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
        this.PH_NO = PH_NO;
    }

    public String getNAME() {
        return NAME;
    }

    public void setNAME(String NAME) {
        this.NAME = NAME;
    }

    public String getAGE() {
        return AGE;
    }

    public void setAGE(String AGE) {
        this.AGE = AGE;
    }

    public String getGENDER() {
        return GENDER;
    }

    public void setGENDER(String GENDER) {
        this.GENDER = GENDER;
    }

    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(String DOB) {
        this.DOB = DOB;
    }

    public String getCOUNTRY() {
        return COUNTRY;
    }

    public void setCOUNTRY(String COUNTRY) {
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

    public String getPH_NO() {
        return PH_NO;
    }

    public void setPH_NO(String PH_NO) {
        this.PH_NO = PH_NO;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    tools:context="com.techyour.bank.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetSet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ocBtnGetSet"
        android:text="Get" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGetSet">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code Updated(MainActivity.java) but getting same error**

```
package com.techyour.bank;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    GetSet getSet;
    List<GetSet> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        checkPermission();
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    public void ocBtnGetSet(View view) throws IOException {
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private void writeXmlToSd(String data) {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AABBCC");

            if (!Dir.exists()) {
                Dir.mkdir();
            }

            File file = new File(Dir, "backup.xml");

            String text = data;

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SD Card Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        TextView tvData;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            tvData = findViewById(R.id.tvData);

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            try {
                xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
                xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
                xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "persons");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= dbHelper.getDataCount().size(); i++) {
                dataList = dbHelper.getAllData(String.valueOf(i));
                getSet = dataList.get(0);

                try {
                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "person");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "name");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getNAME());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "name");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "age");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getAGE());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "age");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "gender");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getGENDER());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "gender");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "dob");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getDOB());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "dob");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "country");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getCOUNTRY());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "country");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "ph_no");
                    xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getPH_NO());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "ph_no");

                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "person");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "persons");
                xmlSerializer.endDocument();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return writer.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            tvData.setText(aVoid);
            writeXmlToSd(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use file writing process in background thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: I don't know how to use thread and asynctask. Can you explain ?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing a whole lot of work in the main Thread. The main thread runs all the user interface work of the app.
Consider running your database code in a separate Thread.

You can find more information in the developer docs about threading here at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

If you offload that work to a thread, make sure your UI tells your user that there is ongoing work in the background so that the user will not abandon the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetSet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ocBtnGetSet"
        android:text="Get" />
```

> ocBtnGetSet

This above function is making problem. Because in this function you are doing DB operations.

You are doing heavy operations on Main Thread. Basically android application on One Main Thread. If you want heavy operations like Database or call API to get data. You can use `AsyncTask`. It runs separately with Main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Move you all heavy work to AsyncTask**

Make AsyncTask Like,

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        try {
            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "persons");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= dbHelper.getDataCount().size(); i++) {
            dataList = dbHelper.getAllData(String.valueOf(i));
            getSet = dataList.get(0);

            try {
                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "person");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "name");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getNAME());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "name");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "age");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getAGE());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "age");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "gender");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getGENDER());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "gender");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "dob");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getDOB());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "dob");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "country");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getCOUNTRY());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "country");

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "ph_no");
                xmlSerializer.text(getSet.getPH_NO());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "ph_no");

                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "person");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "persons");
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();

        tvData.append(writer.toString());

        writeXmlToSd(writer.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And Then execute task in click function by calling

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm still getting that same error after implementing your code.

Comment: Why you assign id of textview in background ? Remove it.

Comment: just log of skipping frame or not responding dialog ?

Comment: Both, showing skipping frames in log and not responding showing in the phone when clicking on the link button.

Comment: How much data ?

Comment: There are 30 rows and 7 colums of data present in the Sqlite Database.

Comment: add  `fos.flush();` before ` fos.close();` Line. Maybe it work.